# Let users upload images from social networks

Tags: views, theming, media, files, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to build a website that gives user's a profile page where they can either upload images from their computer or pull them in from Facebook and Instagram.

Ideally i'd like the user to have an interface where they can select the source of the images and start adding images - Or better yet, have a feed from Instagram *per user* that updates itself.

Currently, I just have an image field and a gallery created with views.

I found a resource online called Filepicker.io but it's not free and Drupal support seems minimal at best: [image]

Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried the [Ink Filepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_inkfilepicker) module? but  Ink Filepicker can be fully branded and is free for up to 5,000 files imported/month. Additional uploads are $0.005 each

Comment: @KrishnaMohan, the [Ink Filepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_inkfilepicker) module is just a Drupal wrapper for the external service (*Filepicker.io*) mentioned by the OP. I believe the pricing information you quote from the project page is outdated. [Current pricing plan](https://www.filepicker.io/pricing/) only indicates a 10 day free trial for any of the regular plans. There is still a crippled free plan with no conversions and no branding for "personal projects", but it looks pretty useless.